# Not sure is my conclusions are good in set-theory exercise?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove equality of sets:

 $f^{-1}(C\cup D)=f^{-1}(C)\cup f^{-1}(D)$ where $f \subseteq X\times Y$ is function and $C,D\subseteq Y$.

My proof goes like this: 
Let $x \in f^{-1}(C\cup D) \iff f(x) \in C\cup D \iff f(x) \in C \vee f(x) \in D \iff x \in f^{-1}(C) \vee x \in f^{-1}(D) \iff x \in f^{-1}(C)\cup f^{-1}(D)  $

Is it all ok? Are all these equivalence signs good or I have just implication somewhere. This one is supicious to me but I can't find counterexample why it wouldn't be good?
$f(x) \in C \vee f(x) \in D \iff x \in f^{-1}(C) \vee x \in f^{-1}(D)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, aside from the fact that you have $D$ in some spots and $U$ in others, it is just fine.

By definition $f(x)\in C$ if and only if $x\in f^{-1}(C)$ (similarly with $D$). Thus, that "suspicious" equivalence is okay. Basically, all you've done is rewritten the two statements in your disjunction. This is no more problematic than saying something like $$(1+x\ge0)\vee(1+y\ge0)\Longleftrightarrow(x\ge-1)\vee(y\ge-1)$$ for real numbers $x,y$.

Comment: Thank you =D I corrected it. I'm stil slow with set-theory (and typing latex =D)